# Remove text from String in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I have a table with 2 columns.(column 2 is basically an append list of multiple emails)

| Caseid | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | FROM: ABHI RATHI <(><<)>ABHIRATHI@XYZ.COM> SENT: FRIDAY, JUNE 17, 2022 12:33 PM TO: VR, SARATH <(><<)>SARATH.VR@ABC.COM>; SUBJECT: RE: LOG # 20092017656 : [ SECURITY TEAM IDENTIFY THERE IS SUSPICION ACTIVITY ] [ ACTIONS REQUIRED ] FROM: YUAN LN <(><<)>YIQUANLIN@XYZ.COM> SENT: FRIDAY, JUNE 10, 2022 3:40 PM TO: VR, SARATH <(><<)>SARTH.VIR@ABC.COM> SINGH, ROHINI <(><<)>ROSHINI.SINGH@PQR.COM>SUBJECT: RE: LOG # 20092017656 : HI SARTH SORRY FOR THE LATE REPLY AS I AM ON LEAVE TODAY CAN WE HAVE A CALL NEXT MONDAY? THANKS AND REGARDS YUAN |

REQUIRED OUTPUT:

| CaseId | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | SUBJECT: RE: LOG # 20092017656 : [ SECURITY TEAM IDENTIFY THERE IS SUSPICION ACTIVITY ] [ ACTIONS REQUIRED ]. SUBJECT: RE: LOG # 20092017656 : HI SARTH SORRY FOR THE LATE REPLY AS I AM ON LEAVE TODAY CAN WE HAVE A CALL NEXT MONDAY? THANKS AND REGARDS YUAN |

Remove from 'FROM:' till '>' before 'subject'. Only keep the contents and remove unnecessary text

I tried this :

```sql
with test as
(
 select 'FROM: ABHI RATHI <(><<)>ABHIRATHI@XYZ.COM> SENT: FRIDAY, JUNE 17, 2022 12:33 PM TO: VR, SARATH <(><<)>SARATH.VR@ABC.COM>; SUBJECT: RE: LOG # 20092017656 : [ SECURITY TEAM IDENTIFY THERE IS SUSPICION ACTIVITY ] [ ACTIONS REQUIRED ] FROM: YUAN LN <(><<)>YIQUANLIN@XYZ.COM> SENT: FRIDAY, JUNE 10, 2022 3:40 PM TO: VR, SARATH <(><<)>SARTH.VIR@ABC.COM> SINGH, ROHINI <(><<)>ROSHINI.SINGH@PQR.COM>SUBJECT: RE: LOG # 20092017656 : HI SARTH SORRY FOR THE LATE REPLY AS I AM ON LEAVE TODAY CAN WE HAVE A CALL NEXT MONDAY? THANKS AND REGARDS YUAN' as text from dual
 )
select regexp_replace(text, 'FROM:[[:print:]]*[\.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}[\>]','' )
from test
```

Got output:

> SUBJECT: RE: LOG # 20092017656 : HI SARTH SORRY FOR THE LATE REPLY AS I AM ON LEAVE TODAY CAN WE HAVE A CALL NEXT MONDAY? THANKS AND REGARDS YUAN

Issue:
Contents of first email is missing.

required output:

> SUBJECT: RE: LOG # 20092017656 : [ SECURITY TEAM IDENTIFY THERE IS SUSPICION ACTIVITY ] [ ACTIONS REQUIRED ] SUBJECT: RE: LOG # 20092017656 : HI SARTH SORRY FOR THE LATE REPLY AS I AM ON LEAVE TODAY CAN WE HAVE A CALL NEXT MONDAY? THANKS AND REGARDS YUAN

Comment: Removing the headers _before_ inserting the email message into your database would seem like a much superior solution. The uppercasing seems like a serious usability problem.

Comment: Are you not missing a few parameters? For example the occurrence which should be set to 0 to replace all matched substrings? I'm not sure if this is the default though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use non-greedy (indicated by a question mark) match between `FROM` and `SUBJECT` and replace this match with `SUBJECT`:

```
with sample(caseid, val) as (
  select 101, q'^FROM: ABHI RATHI <(><<)>ABHIRATHI@XYZ.COM> SENT: FRIDAY, JUNE 17, 2022 12:33 PM TO: VR, SARATH <(><<)>SARATH.VR@ABC.COM>; SUBJECT: RE: LOG # 20092017656 : [ SECURITY TEAM IDENTIFY THERE IS SUSPICION ACTIVITY ] [ ACTIONS REQUIRED ] FROM: YUAN LN <(><<)>YIQUANLIN@XYZ.COM> SENT: FRIDAY, JUNE 10, 2022 3:40 PM TO: VR, SARATH <(><<)>SARTH.VIR@ABC.COM> SINGH, ROHINI <(><<)>ROSHINI.SINGH@PQR.COM>SUBJECT: RE: LOG # 20092017656 : HI SARTH SORRY FOR THE LATE REPLY AS I AM ON LEAVE TODAY CAN WE HAVE A CALL NEXT MONDAY? THANKS AND REGARDS YUAN^'
  from dual
)
select
  caseid
  , regexp_replace(val, 'FROM.+?(SUBJECT)', '\1') as replaced
  , val
from sample
```

| CASEID | REPLACED | VAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | SUBJECT: RE: LOG # 20092017656 : [ SECURITY TEAM IDENTIFY THERE IS SUSPICION ACTIVITY ] [ ACTIONS REQUIRED ] SUBJECT: RE: LOG # 20092017656 : HI SARTH SORRY FOR THE LATE REPLY AS I AM ON LEAVE TODAY CAN WE HAVE A CALL NEXT MONDAY? THANKS AND REGARDS YUAN | FROM: ABHI RATHI <(><<)>ABHIRATHI@XYZ.COM> SENT: FRIDAY, JUNE 17, 2022 12:33 PM TO: VR, SARATH <(><<)>SARATH.VR@ABC.COM>; SUBJECT: RE: LOG # 20092017656 : [ SECURITY TEAM IDENTIFY THERE IS SUSPICION ACTIVITY ] [ ACTIONS REQUIRED ] FROM: YUAN LN <(><<)>YIQUANLIN@XYZ.COM> SENT: FRIDAY, JUNE 10, 2022 3:40 PM TO: VR, SARATH <(><<)>SARTH.VIR@ABC.COM> SINGH, ROHINI <(><<)>ROSHINI.SINGH@PQR.COM>SUBJECT: RE: LOG # 20092017656 : HI SARTH SORRY FOR THE LATE REPLY AS I AM ON LEAVE TODAY CAN WE HAVE A CALL NEXT MONDAY? THANKS AND REGARDS YUAN |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PMoTDFRd)

But your sample data has extra punctuation between the last `>` and `SUBJECT` (semicolon in the first occurrence and nothing at the last occurrence), so you may need an extra match pattern for allowed set of characters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what *Oracle*'s regular expression engine can do, but if it handles positive lookaheads and groups then I would use the following pattern:

```
/\s*\bFROM:.*?(?=\bSUBJECT:)(.*?)(?=\s\bFROM:|$)/gi
```

Replaced by `$1.` in order to put the subject back with a final dot after it.

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/Wi19AK/1

Now, if this one doesn't work on *Oracle* then you could just try to remove
the `FROM: ...` part. But as you don't always finish the field with a `>`
you will still have to capture the `SUBJECT:` and put it back. But this
way you don't use a lookahead:

```
/\s*\bFROM:.*?\bSUBJECT:/gi
```

But with this simpler pattern, you don't solve the dot that you want
to add after each subject. See it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/Wi19AK/2

To understand the pattern itself, look at the links on regex101, as
they give us a nice explanation on the right.

### EDIT for *Oracle*

**As *Oracle* doesn't handle `\b` either** (rather surprising for such
a well known DB engine) you'll have to do without it. It's less precise
but it should be OK as these words are followed by the `:` char so
probably not in the rest of your content.

Search for `\s*FROM:(.*?)SUBJECT:` and replace by `. SUBJECT:`.

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/Wi19AK/4

You'll then have to get rid of the first dot and space with a
second search-replace with `^\.\s` as pattern and an empty replacement.

In SQL:

```sql
regexp_replace(
  regexp_replace(
    val,
    '\s*FROM:(.*?)SUBJECT:',
    '. SUBJECT:'
  ),
  '^\.\s',
  ''
)
AS corrected_val
```

Comment: Unfortunately Oracle doesn't support word boundaries (`\b`) and lookarounds in the pattern

Comment: Oracle does not support `\b` word boundaries or look-ahead or look-behind.

Comment: @astentx What a pitty! well, we could do without it. A bit less precise.